# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next' , This error is occuring on line 40

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class Stack:

# Constructor to initialize the root of linked list
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size=0

    def isEmpty(self):
        self.size=0

    # The method push to push element into
    # the stack
    def push(self, data):

        newNode = node(data)
        newNode.next = self.root
        self.root = newNode
        return

    def pop(self):

        # base case
        if (self.isEmpty()):
            return -1
        # delete a node from list
        temp = self.root
        self.root = self.root.next
        popped = temp.data
        return popped
```

Comment: What is your question? You are trying to use the `next` attribute of something that is `None`. The error message is basically self-explanatory. What is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

`self.isEmpty()` is not doing what you probably want it to do. It's merely sets `self.size` to 0, and not actually checking if the list is empty.

This means, when the list has no elements (`self.root` is None), you are going to try to assign `self.root.next` to `self.root`, but there is no such thing as `self.root.next`.

You probably want to fix `isEmpty()` to check if `self.root` is None.